# How to cite multiple references with explicit theorem numbers?

Tags: citing

I would like to cite in the same place two different sources with the explicit indication of the Theorem or Proposition I want to recall. The output I want to obtain is the following:

**[12, Theorem I.2.21; 13, Proposition 2.1]**

or a similar one, meaning I would like the number of the theorem/proposition to be right after the number of the referenced item. But if I use (assuming that 'kan' is the citation key for the 12-th item in my references and 'serre' is the one for the 13-th)

`\cite[Theorem I.2.21, Proposition 2.1]{kan, serre}`

the output is **[12, 13, Theorem I.2.21, Proposition 2.1]**, which I find confusing and don't like. Anyone knows how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest `\usepackage{natbib}` and something like:

```
\citetext{\citealp[Theorem I.2.21]{kan}; \citealp[Proposition 2.1]{serre}}
```

(If you prefer not to hardwire the semicolon, then you'd need to take it from `\NAT@sep`.)

The following is produced with:

```
\setcitestyle{numbers,square,semicolon}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

[image: result 1]

I think this would look better with author-year citations, using

```
\citetext{\citealt[Theorem I.2.21]{kan}; \citealt[Proposition 2.1]{serre}}
```

(i.e., `\citealt` instead of `\citealp`) and without the `\setcitestyle` command above:

[image: result 2]